# Calling a function after a Push notification has been recieved while the app is closed?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to call a certain method from the AppDelegate after a push notification has been received while the app is in inactive state (Terminated)?

I know it is possible to call a method when the app is opened from the notification (eg. tapping a banner in notification center.)

I'd like to perform a small geolocation check when a push is received from my server. Is that possible and wont my app get rejected?

Comment: You can see my Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741618/didreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler-not-being-called-when-app-is

Comment: @IdanMoshe, is this case his application is terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle a push notification in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

when app is in background state and working, not inactive.
But you can send a sound & text notification when app is inactive but you can't do anything.

Inactive I mean suspended - not working at all (neither foreground nor background).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Your app badge will only be updated if you are sending it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that allows doing something after push on inactive app without user interactions

Answer (score 0):

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW2): "`Inactive State`:: The app is running in the foreground but is currently `not receiving events`. (It may be executing other code though.) An app usually stays in this state only briefly as it `transitions to a different state`."

So It's not possible that you want.