# Swift AppDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotification with completion handler - cannot add "remote-notification" in plist

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am trying to get this somewhat new `didReceiveRemoteNotification` AppDelegate method to work.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741618/didreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler-not-being-called-when-app-is) thread and the problem I have is that no matter what I do, I cannot add "remote-notification" to my plist.

At best, I can select a value from a pre-populated list associated with `Required background modes`. If I try to manually enter a value, xcode simple ignores it and switches back to the first value in the list `App downloads content in response to push notifications`

Has anyone managed to add remote-notification to Required background modes? If so, how?

I am using swift 2, xcode 7 and minimum ios is 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

While in the plist I cannot put the string "remote-notification", in a text editor, the default value of `App downloads content in response to push notifications` is actuallay written as:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
       <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```