# It is possible to process remote notifications and avoid showing it to the user?

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have an application in iOS that receives push notifications through GCM ([Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)) and APNS . These notifications contain some data that has to be processed before showing anything to the user.

After data processing, I generate a local notification with proper information to the user.

I see this behaviour:

- With the app in foreground I only see the local notification.
- With the app in background I see both notifications, remote and local.
- With the app not even running, no notification is shown.

**Can I show only my local notification after processing some data? (at least when the app is in background)**

I have read about using content-available property as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6), but the behaviour is almost the same.

Comment: Yes, you can.
Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741618/didreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler-not-being-called-when-app-is

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution (thanks to @DmytroShvecov for the pointer).

It is necessary to follow the official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6) and follow these steps in the server:

- Include inside `aps` keys `alert`, `badge` and `sound` but with blank value.
- Include `content-available` key with `1` as value (if you want your notifications to be processed in background without interaction of the user.
- Include any `acme` key to be treated as custom payload with your data.

This is an example of everything working together:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "",
    "badge" : "",
    "sound":"",
    "content-available": 1
  },
  "acme": {
    "what": "ever",
    "you": "want"
  }
}
```