# How can I know that push notification delivered or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) to receive push notifications.

Everything is working for me.

But from my server side they will send notifications continuously to my app with time as body up to some time.

Now I have to push notification only once where the time I am getting from server reaches current time.

Before current time and after current time notifications should not be shown.

I don't have any idea how to do this.

Can any one explain if is there any way to get this.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are asking, but push notification is a "best effort" service; there is no indication that a message has been delivered

Comment: You must send silence notifications. And then show local notification when u need. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741618/didreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler-not-being-called-when-app-is

Comment: @DmytroShvecov How can I differentiate between silent notification and push notification?

Comment: Silence notification will not shown to user. You must send all notification in that way. And handle them in program, and then show local notification if needed. look at link what i posted before

Comment: @DmytroShvecov Thanks for the responce

Comment: @DmytroShvecov But if i got silent notification from server how can I push notification to user?

Comment: I just not exactly understand what you want, and what you asked, like mention first commentator).
You can show notification to user with UILocalNotification.

Comment: From a deleted answer comes this link to a very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830597/how-to-know-push-notification-delivery-status/25830955#25830955

Answer (score 1):

I have created an endpoint on a PHP server that takes an autoId referring to a `notifications/$autoId` in my realtime database. The sender of the notification writes the notification data to the database and if successful sends a POST request to `http://myserver.com/notifications/$autoId/send`.

This seems authentication-less however no one will know the notification id being sent apart from the user who created it and the user who receives it. On the server side, when the message successfully sends using FCM, we can set `{"sent": true}` to prevent it from being sent more than once. When the notification is received by the user, we set `{"received": true}`.

```
{
    "notifications": {
        "$autoId": {
            "sent": false,
            "received": "false",
            "userInfo": {
                "notificationId": "$autoId",
                "toId": "$toUid",
                "fromId": "$fromUid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize you notification arrival schedule by implementing cron jobs on your server.

And if you are using any `API` to push notification to any device just get the success message or delivered message after calling.